Getting SVM version for each Block/Epoch
I'm having a unique problem that requires a bit of information from the general hive mind.
What I'm trying to do is create a relational list of Epochs/Blocks and what SVM version was used to generate them.
I'm aware that I can get the current version, but with what I am familiar there is currently no on-chain way to get that for the blocks themselves.
My question would be a 3-parter:

Is there a way for me to get a schedule of SVM releases and at what Epoch they become the primary driver on mainnet
Is Epoch enough, or do I need to go to the granular level (block) since the releases might not coincide with the new epoch
Would there be some on-chain way of checking this that I have not considered?


Let's start off by saying: this is a hard problem that mixes a lot of different parts of the blockchain, not just the SVM.
By "SVM version", I'm guessing that you mean the version of the validator that executed the transaction. This is already a bit unclear, because validator releases are backwards compatible -- meaning that a few different validator versions could have executed the transaction. Validators only diverge due to "feature gates" which introduce breaking behavior, but this kind of breaking behavior might be outside of the SVM.
If you want the validator version, you'll need to look back through the entire release schedule for all minor versions of the Solana validator at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/releases and https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/releases -- this information is not available on-chain unfortunately.
For an on-chain solution, you could hash together the pubkeys of all enabled feature gates, which are given by pubkeys in https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/master/sdk/feature-set/src/lib.rs -- you would need the account state of all these pubkeys at the start of the epoch to know which were enabled. This requires a snapshot of the full account state at the start of each epoch.
Finally, as for the question about whether Epoch is enough, the answer (for now) is "yes". Breaking features are enabled at the start of epochs, and never in the middle of epochs.
